# Where is my server.ini and php.ini File on HHVM?

Tags: hhvm

i have installed HHVM with Homebrew and i can't find on my Mac OS the server.ini and the php.ini files.. hope you can help me guys.

Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the standard brew configuration location, which is typically `/usr/local/etc` -- so those to files would typically be under `/usr/local/etc/hhvm/`. This can differ if you have homebrew in a nonstandard configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question, do you know where I can get a Hack MVC? Like a Framework or something else..